# How do I create a console app that does not end but wait for events?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, tweetinvi

I want to create a bot with the twitter stream API. So basically an event gets triggered and I do something.

I want to let it run in a docker container in a linux-environment.

The issue I have is that my console just closes itself. Here is my code

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    var  credentials = new TwitterCredentials(consumerKey: "",
                                              consumerSecret: "",
                                              accessToken: "",
                                              accessTokenSecret: "");    
    var stream = Tweetinvi.Stream.CreateFilteredStream(credentials);

    stream.AddFollow(someUserId,
                     tweet =>
                     {
                         doSomething(tweet);
                     });

    stream.MatchingTweetReceived += (s, e) =>
    {
        doSomething(e.Tweet);
    };

    await stream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditionsAsync();
}
```

I wait for the Stream to be started but then the console closes itself. I'm not waiting for any events. How can I change this?

Comment: Creating a `Worker Service` application may be better suited for what you're trying to accomplish. You can create one from the ASP.NET Core Worker Service template.

Comment: A Quick way: try a `Console.ReadLine();` after the `await ....`. You the have to press [Enter[ to terminate the application

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `StartStreamMatchingAllConditionsAsync` completes at some point, and this is causing your application to exit.

What you need is something that you can `await` on but will never complete. [Task.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Delay_System_Int32_) can do this for you. Just make this the last line of your function:

```
await Task.Delay(-1);
```

Comment: then the events wont be triggered

Comment: @amkinlgimwqjbfnrdi - Aren't they called on a different thread when the event fires?